# Storing results from calculations into an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, razor

I am using razor C# without MVC. I am using data from SQL to do calculations on the fly. What I want to do is store the results into an array so that I can sum the total later on.

```
 conn.SQL = ....

        //set up connection
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(...);
        connect.Open();

        //create the data reader
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(....., connect);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.Dispose();


        while (dr.Read())
        {


            foo = 0
            bar = 0;

            //get local variables from database

            foo = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(dr["foo"]), 2);

            bar = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(dr["bar"]), 2);

            foo = var - foo2 - foo3;
 try
            {
                if ((foo / var) >= .5)
                {
                    if (foo <= 0.00)
                    {
                        bar = 0.00;
                        bar = var * .5;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MyVar = bar * .7 - foo;//This is the calculation done on the fly.
                        foo = bar * .5;
                        // MyVar_array = [];// This is the array I want to store the results to summed later on 
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
```

These are the calculations then I am displaying them in a table 
  @foo.ToString("C")

The data displays correctly and the calculations are correct> The problem is I'm trying to get a total from this column. When trying to us an array I and getting a variety of errors from it doesn't exist in the current context. After which I will declare at the top of my code then I will receive an error saying I can use this variable in this scope.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My friend, you still have not asked a question. What is giving you difficulty? Do you not know how to declare the array? How to update it? How to display its contents? Your example doesn't contain any loop, SQL, or HTML, so I have no idea where you are having trouble or how the code in your example applies to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but this is how you would store something in an array.

```
decimal[] MyVar_array = new decimal[1];
MyVar_array[0] = new decimal(0.123);
//access the first item in the array like this
Debug.Print(MyVar_array[0].ToString());
```

I really think you want to look into using classes though. It'll be harder to manage that item [0] corresponds with whatever variable you are setting to it. Plus with an array, you need to now how big it will be when creating it. Dealing with objects is much easier. Something like this

```
public class MyStuff
{
    public decimal MyVar
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStuff myData = new MyStuff();
        myData.MyVar = new decimal(0.123);
        Debug.Print(myData.MyVar.ToString());
        Debug.Print("");
    }
```

It's much easier working with objects to manage and organize your data.

Comment: I'm trying to add up the data in a column. The numbers that I am trying to store are results of calculations done from data coming out of MS SQL. Since I'm using Razor without MVC the display is a  HTML table   <td>@bar.ToString("C")</td>. I have a for loop what loops through and gives the size of the table but because the calculations are done on the fly I'm having difficulty summing those numbers up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use List and it is much easier

```
List<decimal> x = new List<decimal>();

try
{
    if ((foo / var) >= .5)
    {
        if (foo <= 0.00)
        {
            bar = 0.00;
            bar = var * .5;
        }

        else
        {
            MyVar = bar * .7 - foo;//This is the calculation done on the fly.
            foo = bar * .5;
            // MyVar_array = [];// This is the array I want to store the results to summed later on 
        }

    }
    //x.Add(foo); im not sure which is you are storing
    x.Add(bar);

}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

then you can call each indexes like arrays

```
decimal firstvalue = x[0];
decimal secondvalue = x[1];
```